# Extracting the Bayesian p-value from lmer model in R

Tags: r, bayesian, lme4, p-value

I am trying to **extract Bayesian p-values** (i.e., *the proportion of estimates that are >0 if the point estimate is negative, or where the point estimate is positive, the proportion of estimates that is < 0)*) from a `lmer` model I have made. I understand "p-values" are inherently frequentist, but I require the Bayesian p-values to appease a Reviewer ([similar to this user](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148649/how-to-respond-to-reviewers-asking-for-p-values-in-bayesian-multilevel-model)).

For the purposes of reproducibility, I am using a dataset from R to illustrate my question. The dataset:

```
library(datasets)
data(ChickWeight) #importing data from base R
summary(ChickWeight)

 weight           Time           Chick         Diet   
 Min.   : 35.0   Min.   : 0.00   13     : 12   1:220  
 1st Qu.: 63.0   1st Qu.: 4.00   9      : 12   2:120  
 Median :103.0   Median :10.00   20     : 12   3:120  
 Mean   :121.8   Mean   :10.72   10     : 12   4:118  
 3rd Qu.:163.8   3rd Qu.:16.00   17     : 12          
 Max.   :373.0   Max.   :21.00   19     : 12          
                                 (Other):506
```

My real data has both continuous and discrete predictor variables and a random effect for individual identity.

Creating the `lmer` model:

```
install.packages("lme4", dependencies=TRUE)
library(lme4)

m1<-lmer(weight ~ Time + Diet+ (1|Chick), data=ChickWeight)
summary(m1)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: weight ~ Time + Diet + (1 | Chick)
    Data: ChickWeight

REML criterion at convergence: 5584

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0591 -0.5779 -0.1182  0.4962  3.4515 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Chick    (Intercept) 525.4    22.92   
 Residual             799.4    28.27   
Number of obs: 578, groups:  Chick, 50

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  11.2438     5.7887   1.942
Time          8.7172     0.1755  49.684
Diet2        16.2100     9.4643   1.713
Diet3        36.5433     9.4643   3.861
Diet4        30.0129     9.4708   3.169

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr) Time   Diet2  Diet3 
Time  -0.307                     
Diet2 -0.550 -0.015              
Diet3 -0.550 -0.015  0.339       
Diet4 -0.550 -0.011  0.339  0.339
```

Unlike the `ChickWeight` dataset, my real dataset has estimates that are both positive and negative.

I then want to extract the 95% credible intervals from my model `m1`:

```
install.packages(c("MCMCglmm", "arm"), dependencies=TRUE)    
library(MCMCglmm)
library(arm)

sm1<-sim(m1,1000)
smfixef=sm1@fixef #fixed effects
smranef=sm1@ranef #random effects
smfixef=as.mcmc(smfixef) 

posterior.mode(smfixef) #extract estimates for fixed effects
(Intercept)        Time       Diet2       Diet3       Diet4 
  10.489143    8.800899   16.761983   31.684341   28.037318 

HPDinterval(smfixef) ##extract 95% credible intervals for fixed effects
                  lower     upper
(Intercept) -0.05392775 21.960966
Time         8.38244319  9.064171
Diet2       -0.46587564 34.061686
Diet3       17.90445947 53.817409
Diet4       11.17259787 48.467258
attr(,"Probability")
[1] 0.95
```

Now I want to get the Bayesian p-value:

```
install.packages("conting", dependencies=TRUE)
library(conting)
bayespval(object=sm1, n.burnin = 0, thin = 1, statistic = "X2") 
#this last line is the line I am having trouble with

Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

**With how I set up my model `m1`, what is the correct format to extract the Bayesian p-values for each estimate?**

There is an example posted with the [original](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conting/conting.pdf) [package/code](https://rdrr.io/cran/conting/man/bayespval.html), but my model is not set up as their model is.

*I do not need to use this package and would be just as happy to calculate it from my 1000 simulations.* In that case, I would need to know **how to count how many of the estimates are below/above zero. That number / 1000 (total number of estimates) would be the Bayesian p-value.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract Bayesian p-values (*i.e, the proportion of estimates that are >0 if the point estimate is negative, or where the point estimate is positive, the proportion of estimates that is < 0*) you can extract the point estimates for each simulation and then divide by the number of simulations.

To do this using the `ChickWeight` dataset and the above model, you then:

```
library(datasets)
data(ChickWeight)

m1<-lmer(weight ~ Time + Diet+ (1|Chick), data=ChickWeight)

sm1<-sim(m1,1000)
smfixef=sm1@fixef
smfixef=as.mcmc(smfixef) #this has the 1000 simulations in it for the fixed effects 

as.mcmc(smfixef)
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 1000 
Thinning interval = 1 
        (Intercept)     Time        Diet2     Diet3      Diet4
   [1,] 17.52609243 8.381517   7.47169881 46.442343 19.7164997 #simulation 1
   [2,] 16.52854430 8.859378   8.83279931 29.017547 25.4610474 #simulation 2
   [3,]  4.00702870 8.830302  29.68309621 47.459395 35.1939344 #simulation 3
   [4,] 16.44162722 8.599929  15.87393285 31.946265 33.7513144 #simulation 4
   [5,] 21.07173579 8.596701   1.81909415 28.934133 19.0499998 #simulation 5
etc.
```

Then for each column you can code which simulations were above or below zero:

```
p_Time=if_else(smfixef[,2]>0, 1,0) #Time variable (i.e., 2nd column)
```

Because the point estimate for the `Time` variable is positive, you want to count the number of times an estimate for that variable was below zero:

```
sum_p_Time=sum(p_Time<1)
> sum_p_Time
0
```

In this case it says all the estimates are above zero, therefore the Bayesian p-value is < 0.001. This supports what we see when we look at only the point estimate and 95 % credible intervals (i.e. `Time` estimate is 8.80 and 95 % credible intervals are (8.38, 9.06). In both cases we see there is strong support for `Time` having an effect on `weight`.